# Installing Visual studio on 21Gb SSD

Tags: visual-studio

I have 21Gb SSD and 1TB HDD on my laptop. 17Gb is occupied by Windows files on my SSD. Now, when i try to install visual studio it says i must have at least 5Gb of free space on every drive. Does this mean that my PC won't be able to run windows on SSD and visual studio at the same time ?

Comment: Correct, you'll either need to free up space or install to another location.  Have you removed your system restore points?  That's usually some easy free space back.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install Visual Studio 2010 Express somewhere besides C:?](http://superuser.com/questions/118359/how-do-i-install-visual-studio-2010-express-somewhere-besides-c)

Answer (score 0):

Only default installation of Visual Studio consumes 5Gb (or whatever other default required space for other Visual Studio version).

One alternative you could try, is to perform a Visual Studio installation with selective default and hidden components, some of them, like Blend and/or SQL components occupies too much space, and maybe you don't need it for your purposes to reduct the required freespace, however, this will not ensure you could install Visual Studio at all even with the minimal components installed, because the freespace you have is very, very small.

I recommend you to perform a full analysis on which applications installed on your system you can uninstall, a default installation of Windows occupies more or less 12 GB, so you have increased the space some Gigabytes, maybe by installing updates (that you can uninstall or also remove its backups to reduct size) or by applicatiosn that you installed (which can be uninstalled), also, perform some cleaning with **[CCLEANER](https://www.piriform.com/ccleaner/download)**, and after all that, try what I commented above about doing a selective installation of Visual Studio:

- **https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee225237.aspx**

The point is that the installer does not let you to decide which hidden components to install, and this way you can decide.

For example I use this unattend.xml example, designed for Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate (for other version and/or edition is not compatible) which installs Visual Studio only with the required components to develop under VB.Net and C# with no unnecessary extra addons:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<AdminDeploymentCustomizations xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2011/AdminDeployment"> 
<BundleCustomizations TargetDir="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0" NoWeb="default"/> 
<SelectableItemCustomizations> 
<SelectableItemCustomization Id="Blend" Hidden="no" Selected="no"/> 
<SelectableItemCustomization Id="LightSwitch" Hidden="no" Selected="no"/> 
<SelectableItemCustomization Id="VC_MFC_Libraries" Hidden="no" Selected="no"/> 
<SelectableItemCustomization Id="OfficeDeveloperTools" Hidden="no" Selected="no"/> 
<SelectableItemCustomization Id="SQL" Hidden="no" Selected="no"/> 
<SelectableItemCustomization Id="WebTools" Hidden="no" Selected="no"/> 
<SelectableItemCustomization Id="Win8SDK" Hidden="no" Selected="no"/> 
<SelectableItemCustomization Id="SilverLight_Developer_Kit" Hidden="no" Selected="no"/> 
<SelectableItemCustomization Id="WindowsPhone80" Hidden="no" Selected="no"/> 
<SelectableItemCustomization Id="BlissHidden" Selected="yes"/> 
<SelectableItemCustomization Id="HelpHidden" Selected="yes"/> 
<SelectableItemCustomization Id="IntelliTraceUltimateHidden" Selected="yes"/> 
<SelectableItemCustomization Id="LocalDBHidden" Selected="no"/> 
<SelectableItemCustomization Id="NetFX4Hidden" Selected="yes"/> 
<SelectableItemCustomization Id="NetFX45Hidden" Selected="yes"/> 
<SelectableItemCustomization Id="PortableDTPHidden" Selected="yes"/> 
<SelectableItemCustomization Id="PreEmptiveDotfuscatorHidden" Selected="no"/> 
<SelectableItemCustomization Id="PreEmptiveAnalyticsHidden" Selected="no"/> 
<SelectableItemCustomization Id="ProfilerHidden" Selected="no"/> 
<SelectableItemCustomization Id="ReportingHidden" Selected="no"/> 
<SelectableItemCustomization Id="SDKTools3Hidden" Selected="yes"/> 
<SelectableItemCustomization Id="SDKTools4Hidden" Selected="yes"/> 
<SelectableItemCustomization Id="Silverlight5DRTHidden" Selected="no"/> 
<SelectableItemCustomization Id="SQLCEHidden" Selected="no"/> 
<SelectableItemCustomization Id="SQLCLRTypesHidden" Selected="no"/> 
<SelectableItemCustomization Id="SQLDACHidden" Selected="no"/> 
<SelectableItemCustomization Id="SQLDOMHidden" Selected="no"/> 
<SelectableItemCustomization Id="SQLSharedManagementObjectsHidden" Selected="no"/> 
<SelectableItemCustomization Id="StoryboardingHidden" Selected="no"/> 
<SelectableItemCustomization Id="TSQLHidden" Selected="no"/> 
<SelectableItemCustomization Id="VCCompilerHidden" Selected="no"/> 
<SelectableItemCustomization Id="VCCoreHidden" Selected="no"/> 
<SelectableItemCustomization Id="VCDebugHidden" Selected="no"/> 
<SelectableItemCustomization Id="VCDesigntimeHidden" Selected="no"/> 
<SelectableItemCustomization Id="VCExtendedHidden" Selected="no"/> 
<SelectableItemCustomization Id="WinJSHidden" Selected="no"/> 
<SelectableItemCustomization Id="WinSDKHidden" Selected="no"/>
```